# Jena queries combining data properties of individuals and their object properties

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I can do fairly simple SPARQL SELECT and CONSTRUCT queries, and I've also used Jena's SimpleSelector to retrieve statements from Jena models. But I'm not sure on the best way to query Jena models without having to do a lot of post-processing on the results, which makes me wonder if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I want to find the team color and player score for players called Dave on teams that are league.

Using SPARQL SELECT queries I can find separately the colors of teams that are league, and the scores of players called Dave, but how can I specify them both in the same query and get unambiguous results back?

I'm using the following ontology:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY stackont "http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:stackont="http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#hasPlayer -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&stackont;hasPlayer">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&stackont;Player"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&stackont;Team"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#PlayerName -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&stackont;PlayerName">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&stackont;Player"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&owl;topDataProperty"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#PlayerScore -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&stackont;PlayerScore">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&stackont;Player"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;double"/>
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&owl;topDataProperty"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#TeamCategory -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&stackont;TeamCategory">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&stackont;Team"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#TeamColor -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&stackont;TeamColor">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&stackont;Team"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&stackont;Player">
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&stackont;Team"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Team -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&stackont;Team"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player1a -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Player1a">
        <PlayerScore>500</PlayerScore>
        <PlayerName>Bob</PlayerName>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player1b -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Player1b">
        <PlayerScore>100</PlayerScore>
        <PlayerName>Dave</PlayerName>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player2a -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Player2a">
        <PlayerScore>75</PlayerScore>
        <PlayerName>Steve</PlayerName>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player2b -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Player2b">
        <PlayerName>Jack</PlayerName>
        <PlayerScore>200</PlayerScore>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Team1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Team1">
        <TeamColor>red</TeamColor>
        <TeamCategory>league</TeamCategory>
        <hasPlayer rdf:resource="&stackont;Player1a"/>
        <hasPlayer rdf:resource="&stackont;Player1b"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Team2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Team2">
        <TeamCategory>division</TeamCategory>
        <TeamColor>blue</TeamColor>
        <hasPlayer rdf:resource="&stackont;Player2a"/>
        <hasPlayer rdf:resource="&stackont;Player2b"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Team3 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Team3">
        <TeamColor>green</TeamColor>
        <TeamCategory>league</TeamCategory>
        <hasPlayer rdf:resource="&stackont;Player3a"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#Player3a -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&stackont;Player3a">
        <PlayerName>Dave</PlayerName>
        <PlayerScore>125</PlayerScore>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: If you're going to post _most_ of the ontology, could you post the whole thing?  I.e., including the `<rdf:RDF>` element, so that we can copy and paste it into a local file.  It's difficult to work with incomplete data.  You mention that you can select the data that you want using SPARQL queries, just not all at once yet.  Please post those queries, so we know what it is that you're trying to combine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPARQL is a RDF graph query language.  You just need to write a graph pattern that matches the kind of data that you're looking for.  Based on a tentative completion of your data (so that I could run queries against it), it looks like a query like this should work for you:

```
prefix :      <http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#> 

select * where { 
  ?player :PlayerName "Dave" ;
          :PlayerScore ?score .
  ?team :hasPlayer ?player ;
        :TeamCategory "league" ;
        :TeamColor ?color .
}
```

Running this query against the data using Jena's command line tools produces results like this:

```
$ sparql --data leagues.n3  --query query.rq
----------------------------------------
| player    | score | team   | color   |
========================================
| :Player3a | "125" | :Team3 | "green" |
| :Player1b | "100" | :Team1 | "red"   |
----------------------------------------
```

It may be worth looking at the triple pattern in a bit more depth.  The portion about the player:

```
  ?player :PlayerName "Dave" ;
          :PlayerScore ?score .
```

says that `?player` must be bound to some resource that has the value `"Dave"` for the property `PlayerName`, and has a value for the `PlayerScore` property, which is bound to `?score`.  The description of the team is similar, but “connected” to the other pattern in that the value of the `?team`'s `hasPlayer` property must be `?player`:

```
  ?team :hasPlayer ?player ;
        :TeamCategory "league" ;
        :TeamColor ?color .
```

### Appendix A: Your data, tentatively completed

I think your data is more or less the following.  I'm showing it here in Turtle, because it's more human readable.

```
@prefix :      <http://www.semanticweb.org/id117167/ontologies/2013/9/stackont#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Team2  a              owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :TeamCategory  "division" ;
        :TeamColor     "blue" ;
        :hasPlayer     :Player2a , :Player2b .

:Player1b  a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :PlayerName   "Dave" ;
        :PlayerScore  "100" .

:PlayerName  a              owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain         :Player ;
        rdfs:range          xsd:string ;
        rdfs:subPropertyOf  owl:topDataProperty .

:hasPlayer  a        owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:domain  :Team ;
        rdfs:range   :Player .

:Player2a  a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :PlayerName   "Steve" ;
        :PlayerScore  "75" .

:PlayerScore  a             owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain         :Player ;
        rdfs:range          xsd:double ;
        rdfs:subPropertyOf  owl:topDataProperty .

<http://example.org/icecream>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:Team3  a              owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :TeamCategory  "league" ;
        :TeamColor     "green" ;
        :hasPlayer     :Player3a .

:TeamCategory  a     owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain  :Team ;
        rdfs:range   xsd:string .

:Team   a       owl:Class .

:Player2b  a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :PlayerName   "Jack" ;
        :PlayerScore  "200" .

:Team1  a              owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :TeamCategory  "league" ;
        :TeamColor     "red" ;
        :hasPlayer     :Player1a , :Player1b .

:Player1a  a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :PlayerName   "Bob" ;
        :PlayerScore  "500" .

:Player3a  a          owl:NamedIndividual ;
        :PlayerName   "Dave" ;
        :PlayerScore  "125" .

:TeamColor  a        owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:domain  :Team ;
        rdfs:range   xsd:string .

:Player  a                owl:Class ;
        owl:disjointWith  :Team .
```

Comment: Another great answer Joshua, thanks! I've edited the RDF so it's complete now, as requested in the first response. I was struggling with the binding of the object properties without getting lots of ambiguous results, this has really helped.